# Clicking links with WebdriverIO

Tags: javascript, node.js, webdriver-io

I have a web page that I am trying to test via [Webdriver I/O](http://webdriver.io/). My question is, how do I click a couple of links via a test? Currently, I have the following:

```
var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
var client = webdriverio.remote(settings).init()
  .url('http://www.example.com')
  .elements('a')
  .then(function(links) {
    for (var i=0; i<links.value.length; i++) {
      console.log('Clicking link...');
      var link = links.value[i].ELEMENT;
      link.click().then(function(result) {
        console.log('Link clicked!');
      });
    }
  })
;
```

When the above gets executed, I get an error that says "click is not a function" on link. When I print `link` to the console, it looks like JSON, which would make sense since the [documentation](http://webdriver.io/api/protocol/elements.html) says that the elements function returns WebElement JSON objects. Still, I'm just trying to figure out how to click this link.

How does one do such?

Thanks!

Comment: What about find your element by selector and `click` method? `client.click('a', function(err,res) {...})`

Comment: @Valijon That approach will only click the first link. It will not click each link.

Comment: If you need to click couple links with "purpose", set `class` or `id` attributes for that links. Then, via selectors `"#some_id", "a.some_class"` click them. In our project, we use Selenium for Java, and we do click objectively, like login, logout, main page, second page, etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `elementIdClick`
http://webdriver.io/api/protocol/elementIdClick.html

Here is an example

```
var settings = {
  desiredCapabilities: {
    browserName: 'firefox',
  },
};

var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
var client = webdriverio.remote(settings).init()
  .url('http://www.example.com')
  .elements('a')
  .then(function(links) {
    for (var i=0; i<links.value.length; i++) {
      console.log('Clicking link...');
      var link = links.value[i].ELEMENT;
      client.elementIdClick(link).then(function(result) {
        console.log('Link clicked!');
      });
    }
  });
```

Result of the above code will be

`Clicking link...
Link clicked!`

Answer (score 0):

Hello there you could do directly this though:
it clicks all elements a on the page

```
var client = webdriverio.remote(settings).init()
  .url('http://www.example.com')
  .click('a')
  .end()
);
```

you could you a selector to target specific a elements
example:

```
.click("article .search-result .abstract .more")
```